# RL circuit as a feedback loop

Tags: sensor, control-system, passive-networks, negative-feedback

As far as I know for a feedback loop ,

a sensor is required to reduce the effect of disturbances but

1.why a simple RL circuit has a feedback loop but it didn't contain any sensor , so

2. isn't sensing element is not a necessary condition for feedback loop?

Or

I'm missing something? Or  I  have some misconception about feedback systems?

Here is pictorial representation of RL circuit -

[image]

[image]

Comment: *a simple RL circuit* **does not** have a feedback loop. And your equivalent RL circuit is back to front.

Comment: Thanks Andy,  if you have time ,can you explain how it is not a feedback loop because to me it looks ​very similar to a feedback loop !

Comment: **YOU** need to justify why a simple RL circuit could be regarded as a system with feedback (and also justify why you might want to do so). Sure, you can model it as such but that doesn't really get you anywhere. After all I could model a resistive potential divider as a feedback system but that is missing the whole point. Feedback doesn't imply a control loop of any significance.

Comment: I thought that output is reversed back to summing point where it gets subtracted from input ,and that's how feedback system behave , so  where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You are not making much sense. Think about what it is that you are actually having problems understanding. All I have done is try and correct what seem like misconceptions in your question. That is all I have to go on - what you have written. I'm not a mind reader so, be clearer about what it is that is giving you a problem. An RL circuit doesn't have feedback but, can be modelled as a system with feedback but, why bother?

Comment: "*a sensor is required to reduce the effect of disturbances*" Can you mention clearly in the first diagram, what the disturbance signal is? Usually the disturbance is added to the system via another summing junction. Without knowing what disturbance the resistor is supposed to reduce the effect of, it is difficult to answer.

Comment: The "sensor" in this case is the resistor, it turns the current into a voltage ;)

Comment: As Andy aka has mentioned already: Of course, there are different circuits (with and without feedback) having the same transfer function.  So what?

Comment: @AJN  Hi, if we consider R as a system and inductor as a controller , voltage source as an reference and voltage across resistor as output , but I don't show the disturbance signal in picture ,if let's say disturbance signal changes the value of resistor​ then our system works perfectly as -ve feedback because at steady state voltage across resistor will be equal to reference voltage at steady state but if we change output voltage of resistor using some different kind of disturbance signal for example using voltage source then it gets added with reference voltage hence

Comment: Our new reference voltage would be different , but in a feedback system reference signal and all possible disturbance signal should be independent of each other ,so That​ output of system can be controlled no matter what disturbance signal is .is this a reason why we cannot consider this configuration as a feedback system ?

Comment: **1** What is the purpose of considering this system as a feedback system ? **2** You have not shown (or explained) the disturbance signal in either diagram.

Answer (score 1):

I think the OP's question deserves attention;  I myself often wonder if there is negative feedback in some passive devices and processes. Examples are voltage-stabilizing dynamic "resistors" like Zener diodes, current-stabilizing elements, negative "resistors", charging capacitors, etc… But I have always come to the conclusion that they only resemble devices with negative feedback.

On the other hand, many people do not see negative feedback in an emitter follower or in an "active diode" (diode-connected transistor), "current diode" (JFET) and others.  But I believe there is negative feedback there...

In my opinion, the question is whether reaching the equilibrium in all cases in nature can be considered as a process with negative feedback.

I think a prerequisite for this is **to have an amplification in the feedback loop... an amplifier…**

Comment: Hi, if we consider R as a system and inductor as a controller , voltage source as an reference and voltage across resistor as output , but I don't show the disturbance signal in picture ,if let's say disturbance signal changes the value of resistor​ then our system works perfectly as -ve feedback because at steady state voltage across resistor will be equal to reference voltage at steady state but if we change output voltage of resistor using some different kind of disturbance signal for example using  voltage source then it gets added with reference voltage hence

Comment: Our new reference voltage would be different , but in a feedback system reference signal and all possible  disturbance signal should be independent of each other ,so That​ output of system can be controlled no matter what  disturbance signal is .is this a reason why we cannot consider this configuration as a feedback system ?

Comment: @user215805, Interesting thoughts... My notion about these time-dependent passive circuits is that a capacitor finally copies the voltage of the input voltage source and an inductor copies the current of the input current source. I have another notion about the role of the input source in a negative feedback system as a "disturbance". IMO the true input signal of any negative feedback system is zero causing zero output signal. The input voltage added acts as a "disturbance" causing the output voltage to change with the purpose to compensate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have written your circuit equations right and they happen to be the same as the feedback loop you have drawn. No error there. Vr really can be expressed by writing what's left of Vs when the drop in L is taken off and the drop is calculated by using Vr/R as the current of L. You can say Vr depends on what Vr happens to be and that can be presented as a feedback loop.

We can do it for everything. Let A=B/2. Thus 2A=B. It can be written as A=B-A. We cannot decide there must exist a feedback loop, no matter we could write our equation to the same form which fits to some feedback loop. For better confirmation I show what my equation presents:

[image]

The same equation is also true for the next feedback loop:

[image]

That fact gives no reason to me to start to search a hidden sensor in my voltage divider.

Answer (score 0):

it is just a simple 1st LPF like series R, shunt C except positive is common so we can define this as 0V for absolute readings, but for AC it is easier to complement polarities of both input and output and again call former~+ as 0V and the transfer function will not change.

What is the breakpoint for s?  When Z(s)=sL=R.

a simple method is apply KVL or Ohm’s Law in the s domain for impedances and voltage and current.

Answer (score 0):

There's an endless list of electrical circuits that could be mathematically arranged into a negative feedback block diagram but, to quote Yogi Berra, *In theory there's no difference between theory and practice. In practice there is*.

Answer (score 0):

Hi [user215805](/questions/tagged/user215805) you are right that RL circuit can be modeled as the system in below using the thevenin equation. But i think, as you said in the questions, that you have some misconception about feedback systems. But in general these arguments are a bit confusing and also your question it's not trivial.
So let's try to clarify a bit.
*"A feedback system is a system in which input and output are connected togheter so if i modify the input obviusly i modify the output but , much more important, if i modify the output i can modify the input"*. So let's see if definition can be applied to our RL circuit. As shown in schematic (i use two resistor to simplify calculation) we can subdivide our circuit in tree stages: input, system, output.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f232H9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

## INPUT->OUTPUT

If we consider the input-output path as you know \$V_2 = V_1\cdot\frac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}\$

## OUTPUT->INPUT

Now if we consider the output->input path we can see that regardless of V2, V1 is always the same quantity that stimulate the system (see the arrow) so in this case the output stage does not affect the input stage.
But what happen if i'm interested in input current? Nothing, if i substitute the voltage source with current source i always can say that in the system enter the same current from the input. 

**Note** that the fact that, with the voltage source in input, V2 modify the current input doesn't mean that output stage modify the input stage, because my input quantity is not th e current but the voltage input. I can prove this by calculating the input impedance.

### INPUT IMPEDANCE

I put \$V_2 = 0\$, so \$Z_{in} = R_2\$ regardless of output.
So in this case we can't consider our circut a **pure feedback system**.

If you want to learn more about the argument, see what appen at the input/output quantites and impedance of a pure feedback system and compare those results to your circuit.

I use the word **pure** because there are circuit that can be *represent* as a feedback system, but they don't behave like feedback system (as your circuit).

### Why sensing?

First of all, what do you mean with "sensing element"?. Do you intend real sensor or the so called "sampling node?". If you intend real sensor then *"sensing element is not a necessary condition for feedback loop."* . See for example a feedback amplifier. In this case you want to take back the output voltage to the input and you can do it using a resistor, but there also case in which you can use a single wire.


Lastly, feedback theory is a more wide theory. For example you can use tools developed for feedback circuit also in non-feedback circuit (for example blackman formula).

**Last thing to notice**, is that: since this circuit doesn't behave like a feedback system you can solve it using basic notion of electronics such as thevenin and kirchhoff law.
If this circuit behaved like feedback system you cannot solve this using only thevenin or kirchhoff law but you would need other tools.

Please if i made mistakes report them.